# facing diffculties while running real time graph in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino-uno

I'm new to android world. I'm trying to make an Android application to
plot a real time graph using the values obtained by an Arduino sent via
Bluetooth using the HC-06 module using MPAndroid Chart library. My
realtime graph is suddenly stoped while it is running and in logact I
found these messages

```
2019-03-14 14:06:50.161 24475-24480/com.example.fir_s1 I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=251KB, data=200KB
2019-03-14 14:06:50.163 24475-24480/com.example.fir_s1 I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=251KB, data=200KB
2019-03-14 14:06:50.163 24475-24480/com.example.fir_s1 I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
2019-03-14 14:06:50.164 24475-24480/com.example.fir_s1 I/zygote: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
```

I tried to solve the errors with the help of google but I couldn't and
I increased heap size by `--Xmx6g`. Any help on this would be greatly
appreciated.

Comment: Increasing the heap size won't help with the app runtime issues. you could try with `android:largeHeap="true"`, but compiler flags won't affect anything.

Comment: i tried. but it is not working...what can i do